# Special Meaning for Pointer Value 0x7c7c7c7c

Tags: c++, linux, pointers

While debugging a Linux app, I found a pointer with the suspicious value 0x7c7c7c7c.  Does that particular value indicate anything?

(I ask because I know from my MSVC days that in a debug build, values like 0xcdcdcdcd or 0xdddddddd would be stored into heap blocks that were uninitialized, freed, or otherwise invalid.  Some people use magic values like 0xdeadbeef or 0xcafebabe in uninitialized memory.  I'm guessing something in libc or elsewhere uses 0x7c7c7c7c as a magic value, but I can't find it documented.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't recognize that magic number, and neither does [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).  I would guess that some code in your program (or in a library you're using) is using `memset()` and hitting your pointer.  Have you grepped your code base case-insensitively for the string "0x7c"?

Comment: "0x7c" is a constant used within the application, but I don't see any way that four of them would be put together.

Comment: How is it used as a constant?  Is it every memset()'d or memcpy()'d anywhere?  Do you have a buffer overflow?

Comment: The app never sets anything to 0x7c.  It reads incoming bytes from a serial port, and there is a switch statement with a "case 0x7c:" clause.  However, that part of the code is not being used, and I know we don't have any buffers filled with 0x7c characters.

Comment: Well there's a probable answer... the only time you'll see the value 0x7C is if you forget to initialise that pointer.

Answer (score 2):

0x7C is an ASCII pipe "|" character. You could search for writes of that character as well 124 and 0x7C as [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9530/adam-rosenfield) suggested.

Answer (score 1):

0x7c7c = 01111100 01111100 in binary.  That could be one of those "most difficult to read" bit patterns that format utilities fill unused space on hard drives with.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `MALLOC_PERTURB_` environment variable is set? If set, it influences how malloc() initializes the allocated memory.